# How can I lock an icon in Android (programmatically)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on an app for elderly people, it will show a big clock and show family pictures/videos posted by family. 
The problem I have is that I need to lock the app's icon on a fixed place on the user's device so it can't be accidentally moved or deleted from the home screen.

How can I lock the icon in place programmatically?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it depends on the launcher the people are using, so no definite answer can be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I lock the icon in place programmatically?

Step #1: Write your own home screen/launcher app.

Step #2: Lock the icon in place in that launcher.

There are no requirements for any other launcher to even *show* an icon, let alone allow third-party apps to control anything about such an icon.